# Ajax not working? Using jQuery to grab a link, send via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, woocommerce

I can add a product to my cart with this link: 
    `<div id="add"><a id="add-link" href="http://example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=1127">Add to Cart</a>`

I have tried to use both GET or POST when it reaches line 7 but I am not getting an alert that the product was added even though it retrieves the correct url in line 6. Can someone tell me what is wrong? Help would be great!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a#add-link').click(function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault(); 
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        alert("Now I want to call this page: " + url);
        $.post(url, function () {
            alert("Product added to cart");
        });
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Check you console, any JS error? Any network error? Are you sure your server script works?

Comment: Ah.. my error is Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/mf-custom/shop/?category=Tech&mainsymptom=Virus' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://shop.example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=1127'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: As an unrelated heads up, declaring functions inline (right in the .click()) is much slower than declaring them externally and then just calling them in the .click().
`.click(function(event) {
     //do something
}`
slower than:
`.click(myMethod)

function myMethod(){
    //do something
}`

Comment: @Kalmino I switched my function coding out and replace it with your suggestion but I get a syntax error with yours. Any suggestions why?

Comment: Does the server receive the call?

Comment: @chronotrigga, see if the syntax I posted in the answer clears anything up.  If not, can you paste in the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't make it clear from your post where the request was being directed -- that is, whether you're requesting a resource on your domain or outside of your domain -- but this is a common symptom of a [Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) restriction.

If you're URL variable references a domain other than your own, you can bet this is the direction to pursue.  You could test it by putting in a link that references a local resource, and giving that a try (it should work)

Comment: I see.. The URL's are sourced from my subdomain `shop.example.com` but the location of my script is on my main domain `example.com`. I would have to relocate my script to my subdomain then correct?

Answer (score 0):

So, in your script block, you can declare the handlers and the functions:

```
$(document).ready(myMethod);
$(myButton).click(otherMethod);

function myMethod()
{
    //do some work
    //you can trigger another event in here
    $(myButton).click()
}

function otherMethod()
{
    //more work
}
```

Now, when the document signals that it is ready, it will run `myMethod()`, which fakes a click on the `myButton` element, which has an event handler called `otherMethod()`.  So, just by the document saying "Ready!" it will kick off both events and it will do it more quickly than having the functions declared inline.  Inline, JS has to recompile the function every time the event is hit.  Separating the functions out causes them to only be compiled once, when the JS is loaded.

This will fire an event any time your "Add to Product" link is clicked:

```
$('#add-link').click(addToCart);

function addToCart() //you can optionally get an event parameter in here as well
{
     event.preventDefault();
     var url = $(this).attr("href");
     alert("Now I want to call this page: " + url);
     $.post(url, function ()
     {
         alert("Product added to cart");
        //I'm not 100% on this, I don't use the jQuery .post method
     });
}
```

Comment: This is definitely not related to the original post; it's stemming from a discussion in the comments and I needed some extra formatting options :)

Comment: Also, I've heard that Browser/JS version can play a huge factor in this as well.

Comment: I am still a JS newbie. My original is `$('a#add-link').click(function(event)` so where would I insert the a#add-link to have it called via your code?

Comment: It depends on exactly what you're trying to do.  You could use my exact code above but replace `myButton` with `'#add-link'` and when the page loaded, it would automatically click the link.  Does `#add-link` get added to the page AFTER the main load?  if not, then I don't think you need the .ready() event handler.  If `#add-link` is part of the main page, you just need 
`<script>
$('#add-link').click(addToCart)

function addToCart(event)
{
    //do your work, alert the user, etc...
}
</script>`

Also, extra 'a' in your jQuery selector. `$('#add-link')` is for an element with id = 'add-link'

Comment: I stand corrected, the extra "a" in your jQuery ID will filter down to <a> elements with the ID `#add-link`.  However, if your ID is unique, you shouldn't need it.